# How do I efficiently assign a single value per groupby group in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame with a column of non-unique numbers. I want to return a different random number for each of the non-unique values, but return the same random number at each row the non-unique value appears i.e. so the shape of the output dataframe of random numbers matches that of the ungrouped data frame.

I can do this like:
`df.groupby('NonUnique').transform(lambda x: np.random.rand())`

This returns a different random number for each column in `df`, as desired.

However, this is slow for large dataframes, but `np.random.rand(df.size)` is very fast. Is there any way to achieve what I want in a more efficient way? I can't seem to find a way to vectorise the assignment per group...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create array by length of unique values, then use [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html) with `numpy indexing` for repeating:

```
np.random.seed(123)

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('aaabbb')})

a = np.random.rand(df['A'].nunique())

df['B'] = a[pd.factorize(df.A)[0]]
print (df)
   A         B
0  a  0.696469
1  a  0.696469
2  a  0.696469
3  b  0.286139
4  b  0.286139
5  b  0.286139
```

**Detail**:

```
print (pd.factorize(df.A)[0])
[0 0 0 1 1 1]
```

Comment: Can you elaborate, why you would not directly apply factorize? I.e. `s = pd.Series(np.random.randint(1,100,40))
pd.factorize(s)[0]`

Comment: @Fourier - Because OP need random values, `factorize` always return same values `0,1,2...` for unique groups

Answer (score 3):

I you're grouping by anyway, you can just use `ngroup()`

```
df.groupby('column').ngroup()
```

or

```
df.groupby('column').transform('ngroup')
```

Comment: See my comment for @jezrael answer. This will not be random, but sorted natural numbers

Comment: What's the problem in being sorted natural numbers?

Comment: Depends on the OP's task. Mapping by sorted occurrence will be straight-froward

Comment: Tbh I don't understand what OP wants. No example, no data etc. I just answered to the question "How do I efficiently assign a single value per groupby group in Pandas" haha